# Events when clicks on UITableViewCell in objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I encountered an issue in my project as below:

[image]

I wrote a class that is subclass of UIView with:

> 1 - a button
>
> 2 - a table view
>
> 3 - a textfield

I've created an object of that class and add the object to an view of uiviewcontroller. When I click on the button, make the table view appear with a list of all countries and click on a cell of table view, the textfield will get cell's value. I wanna detect events when I touch on a cell of tableview. How can I do that? Please help me, Thank in advance.

P/S: tableview is subView of contentView. Hierarchy as follow:

> ViewController - ScrollView - contentView -(View1, View2...)

Comment: You should read the UITableViewDelegate protocol. The methods you want are there.

Comment: thanks rdelmar, I performed methods of UITableViewDelegate protocol in the my class - uiview and I can detect event in that class. but I wanna, for example: touch on a cell, the progressvalue of progress bar at the top of that image will increase/decrease. Can you suggest for me?

Comment: @VienVu > Show us some code.

Comment: file custom class .h and .m http://textuploader.com/zjr7
http://textuploader.com/zjro

Comment: 4 - progress view bar as follow: http://postimg.org/image/g6llkhoub/

Comment: I wanna touch on cell of tableview, that progress view's value will be changed (increase or decrease). The progress view is subview of uiviewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

Like people said in the comments, all you need is in the `delegate` and `data source`. If you're doing it all programmatically you need to add many things to your code such as `<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>` and also call them on `viewDidLoad`. Then you need to implement some methods. Apple has a vast documentation on all classes and methods, take a look at them. You need the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Hope I could help

Comment: thanks Leonardo. I performed didSelectRowAtIndexPath in my custom class, but how I need to do what to it impact to progress view bar in viewcontroller. progress view bar is subview of view in view controller - number 4 in http://postimg.org/image/g6llkhoub/6050f54f/

Answer (score 0):

`UITableView` had delegate protocol, and for your needs, you only have to implement

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

You will know where you tap by `indexPath`, so you know the location, then you can do whatever you want.

If you want to get the corresponding cell, use

```
- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Simply pass `indexPath` from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: thanks Wingzero. I performed didSelectRowAtIndexPath in my custom class, but how I need to do what to it impact to progress view bar in view controller ?. progress view bar is subview of view in view controller - number 4 in postimg.org/image/g6llkhoub/6050f54f

Comment: if it is your view controller that implemented `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, you could access your sub views via self.view (self is view controller), and other view controller properties. so if the progress bar is defined as your view controller's property, simply call self.progressBar and you get the object, now you could apply your logic to update your views

Comment: I implemented didSelectRowAtIndexPath in my custom class that is  a subview of uiview, not viewcontroller.

Comment: I wanna touch on a cell of tablview from uiviewcontroller and it impact to progress view bar. How can i do that?

Comment: Then your problem would be, how to access view controller from a UIView. That's another big topic to answer, you need to google. But I feel your need to re-consider your app's structure. However, at least, you could add a reference of progress bar to the view. or use some shared objects to pass UIViews and controllers, like appDelegate. There a lot of ways

Comment: @VienVu better to let view controller to implement  the delegate, so you can access many resources then

Comment: @VienVu you could use notification. so your progress bar can get a notification. use whatever you like, but keep your app well structed and flexible

Comment: I also think about using notification to detects changes of uitextfield, but how can the progress bar can get that?

Comment: you add observer to your progress bar

Comment: thanks for your suggestion: "better to let view controller to implement the delegate"+"keep your app well structed and flexible", use view controller to implement the delegate is very good idea for flexible program. Now I using code below for my purpose:  [mytextField addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"text" options:0 context:nil];- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{    if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"text"] && object == self.firstDropdownListView.countriesTextField)
    {//text has changed   
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

You didn't give codes, or something.. So, this is just my assumption of what you're trying.. hmm..

Please give us more details... edit your question if necessary..

```
//viewController.h

@interface viewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *selectedIndexs; 

// use this array as your dataSource for the secondTableView (popup tableView?)

@end

//viewController.m

@implementation viewController

// codes..
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    /*
        you need to store the countries indexPath to cell the name/details
        in this example i will just get the `.textLabel.text`
    */

    UITableViewCell *cell  = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath/*current selected indexPath*/];

    if ([self.selectedIndexs containsObject:cell.textLabel.text]) 
    {
        // [self.selectedIndexs removeObject:cell.textLabel.text]; ]> delete if already in the array

        // return; ]> if you dont want to remove the object just return..
    }
    else
        [self.selectedIndexs addObject:cell.textLabel.text]; // add the country if not exist in the array

}

- (void)showSelectedCountries:(UIButton *)sender //this is the number 1 from the image (Button)
{
    UIView *customViewForSelected = [[UIView alloc] init];

    // then if you have declared a property for `dataSource` inside your 'customViewForSelected' just:

    customViewForSelected.yourSelectedsDataSource = selectedIndexs;

    // then show the view with the table inside which contains only the table.. correct?

    [self.view addSubview:customViewForSelected]; // i just added as subview because i dont know how you call it..
}

@end
```

Hope, you find this helpful.. Cheers..

Answer (score 0):

I created a class: `DropdownListViewCountries` is subclass of `UIView` and include a `button`, a text field and a tableview.

```
@interface DropdownListViewCountries : UIView<UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate>
```

.In `@implementation DropdownListViewCountries`, I implemented `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`
and then I created class: `IndividualPersonalData` is subview of `UIViewController`. This class contains a progress view bar. 
And then I created an object of DropdownListViewCountries and add to `IndividualPersonalData`. 
How to I touch on a cell of `tableview` to change progress view value?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you all for your help. Now for my purpose I found below code to detect events:

```
[self.firstDropdownListView.countriesTextField addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"text" options:0 context:nil];


- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"text"] && object == self.firstDropdownListView.countriesTextField)
    {
        // text has changed
        LogDebug(@"HELLO WORLD");
    }
}
```